# Get relation from definition of stress-energy tensor and the conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, momentum, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Starting from the following definition of stress-energy tensor for a perfect fluid in special relativity :

$${\displaystyle T^{\mu \nu }=\left(\rho+{\frac {p}{c^{2}}}\right)\,v^{\mu }v^{\nu }-p\,\eta ^{\mu \nu }\,}\quad(1)$$

with $$v^{\nu}=\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}\tau}$$ and

$$V^{\nu}=\dfrac{\text{d}x^{\nu}}{\text{d}t}$$ (we have $v^{\nu}=\gamma\,V^{\nu}$)

So, finally, I have to get the following relation :

$$\dfrac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t} + (\vec{V}.\vec{grad})\vec{V} = -\dfrac{1}{\gamma^2(\rho+\dfrac{p}{c^2})} \bigg(\vec{grad}\,p+\dfrac{\vec{V}}{c^2}\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial t}\bigg)\quad(2)$$

**To get this relation, I must use the conservation of energy for $\nu=i$ and $\nu=0$** with :

$$\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}=0\quad(3)$$

If someone could help me to find the equation $(2)$ from $(1)$ and $(3)$, this would be nice to indicate the tricks to apply.

**EDIT 1 :**

For the moment, below where I am :

I recognize in the left member of wanted relation $(2)$ the Lagrangian derivative :

$$\dfrac{\text{D}\,\vec{V}}{\text{d}t}=\dfrac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t} + (\vec{V}.\vec{\nabla})\vec{V}\quad(4)$$

and I can rewrite $(1)$ with the $V^{\mu}$ components like :

$$T^{\mu\nu}=\left(\rho+\dfrac{p}{c^{2}}\right)\,\gamma^2\,V^{\mu}V^{\nu }-p\,\eta^{\mu\nu}\,\quad(5)$$

But from this point, I don't know how to make the link between $(4)$, $(5)$, $(3)$ (the divergence of stress-energy equal to zero),  and $(1)$ ...

Any help is welcome

Comment: You may take a look there : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321982/

Comment: -@Cham . Sorry, this was a mistake, it is the time derivated of pression $p$. I have corrected it.

Comment: The equation I'm getting is this (I use $c = 1$ to simplify things) : \begin{equation}\gamma \, (\rho + p) \, \frac{d \gamma \, \vec{v}}{dt} = - \vec{\nabla} p - \gamma^2 \vec{v} \, \frac{dp}{dt}.\end{equation}  The $\gamma$ factors aren't placed at the same place as in your equation (2), and I get a total time derivative of pressure, not a partial one.

Comment: Ok, after contracting with $\vec{v}$ and playing a bit with my previous equation, I get yours : \begin{equation}\gamma^2 (\rho + p) \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = - \vec{\nabla} p - \vec{v} \, \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}.\end{equation}  Writing a complete answer would be pretty long, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the main steps.  I use $c = 1$ as usual in relativity, and $a, b = 0, 1, 2, 3$ are flat spacetime indices :
\begin{gather}
T^{ab} = (\rho + p) \, u^a \, u^b - \eta^{ab} p,\tag{1} \\[12pt]
\partial_a T^{ab} = u^b u^a \, \partial_a \, \rho + u^b u^a \, \partial_a \, p + (\rho + p)\big( (\partial_a \, u^a) \, u^b + u^a \, \partial_a \, u^b \,\big) - \partial^b p = 0. \tag{2}
\end{gather}
Contract (2) on $u_b$ and use properties $u_b \, u^b = 1$ and $u_b \, \partial_a \, u^b \equiv 0$.  You should get the continuity equation :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
(\rho + p) \, \partial_a \, u^a = -\, u^a \, \partial_a \, \rho.
\end{equation}
Subsitute this constraint into equation (2).  You should get this :
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
(\rho + p) \, u^a \, \partial_a \, u^b = -\, u^b u^a \, \partial_a \, p + \partial^b \, p.
\end{equation}
Write these for simplicity (total proper-time derivative) :
\begin{align}\tag{5}
u^a \, \partial_a \, u^b &\equiv \frac{d u^b}{d\tau},
& u^a \, \partial_a \, p &\equiv \frac{d p}{d\tau}.
\end{align}
Then you get this, for index $b = i = 1, 2, 3$ :
\begin{align}\tag{6}
(\rho + p) \frac{d u^i}{d\tau} = -\, u^i \, \frac{dp}{d\tau} + \partial^i \, p.
\end{align}
Use $u^i = \gamma \, v^i$ and $\partial^i p = -\, \partial_i \, p$ and $d\tau = dt / \gamma$, so (6) becomes a vectorial equation :
\begin{align}\tag{7}
\gamma \, (\rho + p) \frac{d \gamma \, \vec{v}}{dt} = -\, \gamma^2 \, \vec{v} \, \frac{dp}{dt} - \vec{\nabla} \, p.
\end{align}
Now scalar-contract this with vector $\vec{v}$ and use $\dot{\gamma} = \gamma^3 \, \vec{v} \cdot \dot{\vec{v}}$ and the identity $1 + \gamma^2 \, v^2 \equiv \gamma^2$ :
\begin{gather}
\gamma^2 (\rho + p) \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt} + \gamma \, (\rho + p) \, \gamma^3 (\vec{v} \cdot \dot{\vec{v}}) \, \vec{v} = -\, \vec{\nabla} \, p - \gamma^2 \, \vec{v} \, \frac{dp}{dt} \tag{8} \\[12pt]
\gamma^4 (\rho + p)(\vec{v} \cdot \dot{\vec{v}}) = -\, \vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \, p - \gamma^2 \, v^2 \, \frac{d p}{dt}. \tag{9}
\end{gather}
Subsitute (9) into the second term of left part of equation (8).  After some simplification algebra and using
\begin{equation}\tag{10}
\frac{d p}{dt} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} + \vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \, p,
\end{equation}
you should get your equation :
\begin{equation}\tag{11}
\gamma^2 (\rho + p) \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt} = -\, \vec{\nabla} \, p - \vec{v} \, \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}.
\end{equation}
That's the relativistic Euler equation for a perfect fluid.  Usually : $p \ll \rho$ and $\gamma \approx 1$ for a slowly moving fluid.  The last term should be negligible.

Comment: -@Cham thanks. I would like to know how you get the relation $u_b \, \partial_a \, u^b \equiv 0$ ?

Comment: Since $u_b u^b = 1$, just derive it :  $\partial_a (u_b u^b) = 2 \, u_b \, \partial_a \, u^b = 0$.

Comment: -@Cham. Sorry, I didn't understand all the demo : how do you get the continuity equations,(3) i.e : $(\rho + p) \, \partial_a \, u^a = -\, u^a \, \partial_a \, p$ from (1) ?

Comment: You get (3) from (2).  Contract (2) with the components $u_b$, and use $u_b u^b = 1$ and $u_b \, \partial_a \, u^b = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, there was a small error in (3) : $p \Rightarrow \rho$.  I'm fixing it.

Comment: Take note that the - fixed - equation (3) could be written as $\partial_a (\rho \, u^a) = -\, p \, \partial_a \, u^a$.  $j^a = \rho \, u^a$ is the fluid energy current density.  It is conserved for a pressureless fluid ($p = 0$).

Comment: -@Cham ok, that's a little tricky for me. At the end  (eq 11) , you didn't make appear the Lagrangian derivative, i.e $\dfrac{D\vec{v}}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + (\vec{v}.\vec{\nabla}).\vec{v}$ ? you did it for pression $p$ in (eq 10) but not on speed vector $\vec{v}$ : what are the conditions to make appear this Lagrangian derivative for speed vector ?

Comment: The dot is always a total derivative : \begin{equation}\dot{\vec{v}} \equiv \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} \equiv \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \, \vec{v}.\end{equation} This problem is a very good exercice in relativity theory, and it's a cool one.  :-)

Comment: I will give you the award for your help. A last question : in which cases the dot is not a total derivative but the standard form :  $\dot{\vec{v}} \equiv \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$ ? Is it proper to relativity or proper to fluid dynamics ? regards

Comment: The total derivative is proper to fluids, since the velocity is a field in space : $\vec{v} \equiv \vec{v}(t, \vec{r})$.  Thus, when you derive that vector, you should also take into account it's dependance on $\vec{r}$.  For a simple particle : $\vec{v} \equiv \vec{v}(t)$ so $\dot{\vec{v}} = \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} \equiv \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt}$ in its case.